# Convert byte object to python dictonary or json object

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to python.
 I have PHP indexed array. Using get requests I am fetching the data.

data:

```
b'Array\n(\n    [0] => HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\n    [1] => Location: http://www.blahblah.com/\n    [2] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n    [3] => Date: Mon, 29 Oct 2018 09:29:10 GMT\n    [4] => Server: blahblah\n    [5] => Content-Length: 98836\n    [6] => Last-Modified: Mon, 29 Oct 2018 08:13:21 UTC\n    [7] => device_type: Touch\n    [8] => content-language: en\n    [9] => Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=U-i_J9VsfqNazZl3uF4dAj2-7BmV370w58TXINO5UckAel4uGT5O!-115865558; path=/cs; HttpOnly\n    [10] => Keep-Alive: timeout=300\n    [11] => Connection: Keep-Alive\n    [12] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n    [13] => Set-Cookie: NSC_q6.kjp.dpn_dmvtufs_WT.2*80=ffffffff0985006c45525d5f4f58455e445a4a422828;expires=Mon, 29-Oct-2018 09:31:10 GMT;path=/;httponly\n)\n\n'
```

I Want to convert into json object. 
Expected output:

```
{
"[0]" : "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently",
"[1]" : "Location: http://www.blahblah.com/",
"[2]" : "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
"[3]" : "Date: Mon, 29 Oct 2018 09:29:10 GMT",
......,
.....,
```

}

I have tried code to load json:

```
import requests
import json
u1="http://blahblah.com"
req=requests.get("http://gen.demotest.com/httpsProxy/httpsgetheaders.php?url=%s"%(u1))
data=req.content
print(json.dumps(data))
```

but got some error:

```
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: You need to fix how this is being sent. There is no need to include all that `Array\n...` junk; the PHP should be posting form-encoded or JSON data. (And also note, your desired output is not JSON format but again PHP; JSON would look like `{"0": "HTTP...", ...}` or probably better as an array `["HTTP...", ...]`).

Comment: Thanks, @DanielRoseman edited expected output

Comment: If you are getting binary as output, you have to conver to string before doing json.dumps

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to convert the binary response to text. The following lines will do it.

```
data=json.loads(req.text)
print(data)
```

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. This worked for me, thanks @Sushruth N!